# C#: 3D Bitmap transformation in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, 3d, bitmap, windows-store-apps, writeablebitmap

In my Windows Store App, Id like to do a 3D transformation to an image and blit it onto another image. The image should be transformed in a way so that the four corners end up on four predefined coordinates in the second image.
Example: A user can copy his own image into a photo of a poster hanging on a wall, where the photo is not taken at a 90 degree angle.

Is there a framework for doing these kinds of 3D transformation or can someone show me how to do this with matrices-math? I have a basic understanding of how a transformation matrix can work, but how to calculate one myself is beyond my knowledge.

Btw for blitting Im using the WriteableBitmapEx framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Projection` property on every `UIElement`, which for basic 3D transforms you set to a `PlaneProjection` object (which has properties like `RotationX`, `RotationY` and `RotationZ`):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.projection.aspx

If you want to apply complex math, you can set it to `Matrix3DProjection`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.matrix3dprojection.aspx